# Adding delegates: unexpected results when adding two Func<T,TResult>

Tags: c#, operators, expression, func

So this is really bizarre behavior I've observed with using expressions and funcs.

```
public int Age { get; set; }
public EyeColor EyeColor { get; set; }
public int Weight { get; set; }

public Func<Person, bool> AgeAndEyesMatch
    {
        get { return IsPersonYoung().Compile() + PersonHasRightEyeColor().Compile(); }
    }

public Func<Person,bool> AgeAndWeightMatch
    {
        get { return IsPersonYoung().Compile() + IsPersonInShape().Compile(); }
    } 

private Expression<Func<Person, bool>> PersonHasRightEyeColor()
    {
        return person => person.EyeColor == EyeColor;
    }

private Expression<Func<Person, bool>> IsPersonYoung()
    {
        return person => person.Age <= Age;
    }

private Expression<Func<Person, bool>>  IsPersonInShape()
    {
        return person => person.Weight <= Weight;
    }
```

In the console app I've created the following 'people'

```
var mark = new Person
        {
            Age = 30,
            EyeColor = EyeColor.Blue,
            Height = 69,
            Name = "Mark",
            Weight = 185
        };
var austin = new Person
            {
                Age = 70,
                EyeColor = EyeColor.Brown,
                Height = 64,
                Name = "Austin Powers",
                Weight = 135
            };
var napolean = new Person
        {
            Age = 17,
            EyeColor = EyeColor.Green,
            Height = 71,
            Name = "Napolean Dynamite",
            Weight = 125
        };
```

Main program makes a list of these Persons and calls it 'people' simply asks the user to provide the search parameters for age, eye color, and weight. Then calls on the people list  as follows: `newList = people.Where(person => coolKidCriteria.AgeAndEyesMatch(person)).ToList();`
And `newNewList = people.Where(person => coolKidCriteria.AgeAndWeightMatch(person)).ToList();`

Given the parameters of MaxAge = 20, EyeColor = EyeColor.Blue, MaxWeight=150, I would expect the first list to be empty and the second list to only contain Napolean Dynamite... But instead I receive the first list populated with Mark, and the second list populated with Austin Powers and Napolean Dynamite... The only reason I can think of for the unexpected behavior is that the '+' operator for the two Func is causing problems. Just wondering if anyone can explain why. I've deduced that only the 2nd func of the two is being evaluated: AgeAndEyeColor = (age does not evaluate) + (eye color match for Mark only) and AgeAndInShape = (age does not evaluate) + (Austin and Napolean .InShape == true)

And I apologize for the discriminating tone of the app... really this is just a learning thing for me and I had no other context.

Comment: Should `+` be a `&&`?

Comment: Tried that. Compile time error (you cannot use the & operator for operands Func<T,Tresult> and Func<T,Tresult>

Comment: @PhilipPittle The getter is returning a Func (multicast delegate) not a bool.

Comment: Sorry for editing the title, I think it now says more about the problem. Please improve if you don't like how I worded it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `+` on two `Func<int, bool>`s, you are *not* telling C# to create a single `Func<int, bool>` that calls your two original functions and `&&`s together the results. Instead, you are telling C# to create a [*multicast delegate*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173175.aspx) that calls both functions and *returns the last result*.

For example,

```
static Func<int, bool> Fizz = i => i % 3 == 0;
static Func<int, bool> Buzz = i => i % 5 == 0;
static Func<int, bool> FizzBuzz = Fizz + Buzz;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fiveIsFizzBuzz = FizzBuzz(5); // gives true
}
```

If you want an `&&`, you'll have to do it manually:

```
static Func<int, bool> FizzBuzz = i => Fizz(i) && Buzz(i);
```

If everything has to be an expression, you can use the following:

```
static Expression<Func<int, bool>> Fizz = i => i % 3 == 0;
static Expression<Func<int, bool>> Buzz = i => i % 5 == 0;
static Expression<Func<int, bool>> FizzBuzz = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
    Expression.AndAlso(Fizz.Body, Expression.Invoke(Buzz, Fizz.Parameters[0])),
    Fizz.Parameters[0]);
```

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around this, I like this answer but can you give an example of how to utilize the Expression.AndAlso ? I've tried and now `var theList = people.Where(person => coolKidCriteria.AgeAndEyesMatch(person)).ToList();` is broken with "Method, Delegate, or Event Expected" ----- public Expression<Func<Person, bool>> AgeAndEyesMatch
        {
            get { return Expression.Lambda<Func<Person,bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(IsPersonYoung(),PersonHasRightEyeColor())); }
        }

Comment: @MegaMark I've added how to make an Expression out of &&ing two Expressions together, but I'm not sure how you're getting your specific error there.

Comment: GOT IT!!!! `var theList = people.Where(person => coolKidCriteria.AgeAndEyesMatch.Compile().Invoke(person)).ToList();` Thanks all for the help. I still don't really get the new code you posted @Rawling but I plopped it in and changed the call for it as I just posted... and poof!.... spoke too soon... runtime error... argh!

Comment: @MegaMark That's a shame. I'd be lying if I said I 100% understood the last bit (why do you have to call the second expression with the parameter of the first?) but I've tried my Fizzbuzz on a list of ints using your style of `Where` and it works for me. What error do you get?

Comment: Invalid Operation Exception: `variable 'person' of type 'ExpressionsBuilder.Person' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`... it seems as though I'm really not understanding expression trees at all

Comment: I think it's because your expressions are returned from methods... are you doing something like `(Expression.AndAlso(x().Body, ...), x().Parameters[0])`? I think you'd need to store the result of  `x()` so you're using the *same expression instance* to get the `Body` and the `Parameters[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this before... I will keep searching for the reference:

`public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
        {
            var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
        }`

Then I use it like this:

`public Func<Person, bool> AgeAndEyesMatch
        {
           get { return IsPersonYoung().And(PersonHasRightEyeColor()).Compile(); }
        }`

In the console:

`var theList = people.Where(person => coolKidCriteria.AgeAndEyesMatch(person)).ToList();`

So THIS works... but again I have to give credit to whoever came up with the extension method for And... it was NOT me... but this I've found to work.